# AngularJS - Passing object into ng-include (dynamically)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

Below i have a working example... but with one problem... node.title inside the html works fine... but when `{{node.title}}` into the ng-include file... doesn't work. Only global $scope is visible and not "node" object

```
var element = angular.element($(".withOptions"));
var scope = element.scope();
var injector = element.injector();
var compile = injector.get('$compile');


compile(
       '<li id="list_77"><div><i class="icon20 i-folder-open"></i>'+node.title+' <i class="icon16 i-arrow-down-2"></i><div ng-include="\'http://localhost/test/public/theme\'"></div></div></li>'
       )(scope).appendTo($(".withOptions"));
```

Comment: where do you run this code, in directive? Can you reproduce it in plunker/fiddle?

Comment: not in directive... just inside a function to my controller

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws exception when you call:

```
compile(
       '<li id="list_77"><div><i class="icon20 i-folder-open"></i>'+node.title+' <i class="icon16 i-arrow-down-2"></i><div ng-include="\'http://localhost/test/public/theme\'"></div></div></li>'
       )(scope).appendTo($(".withOptions"));
```

Because there is no `appendTo` method when you call `compile("yourtemplate")(scope)`

You should try:

```
compile(
           '<li id="list_77"><div><i class="icon20 i-folder-open"></i>'+node.title+' <i class="icon16 i-arrow-down-2"></i><div ng-include="\'http://localhost/test/public/theme\'"></div></div></li>'
           )(scope,function(clonedElement,scope){
                clonedElement.appendTo($(".withOptions"));
          });
```